# cant focus on tinymce inside colorbox

Tags: jquery, tinymce, colorbox

I am creating a tinymce editor inside a colorbox.  The first time the colorbox loads up, it works fine.  Subsequent times, I can't click or tab to get focus on the tinymce editor.

I am using tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceAddEditor', true, 'tbContent'); and tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor', true, 'tbContent'); to create and remove the editor when the colorbox opens/closes.  I am using version 4.1.9 of tinymce.

Any ideas on this one?

Comment: a quick update on this one, i have done some further testing and noticed on the second load of the colorbox, the head and body elements for the tinymce iframe are completely empty.

For example, the body tag normally has an id of tinymce with a class of tiny-mce-body.  On second load these are gone and any content inside the body tag is also gone.

I am suspecting when the tinymce init function runs, it adds some content to the doc somewhere which is required when the tinymce is reinitialised.  When the colorbox is closed, this content is removed and tinymce does not initialise properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'm still not sure exactly what the problem was, but I came across some posts which suggested using a settimeout for initiating the tinymce (which i hate), so i tested using the onComplete event of the colorbox to initialise tinymce and that did the trick.

I also removed the tinymce using the onCleanup event of colorbox.

No idea why tinymce worked on first load and not afterwards, but this seems to solve the problem.